# When I use intransitive words, should I put the adverb after the intransitive words?

Tags: grammar, australian-english

For example:

> She sings loudly

In which stuation can I put the adverb before the intransitive verb?

Can I say:

> Someone totally is beautiful

or

> Someone is totally beautiful

Answer (score 1):

Only verbs, not other words, can be transitive or intransitive. Transitive verbs take a direct object, Intransitive verbs do not. Many verbs can be ued in either a transitive or an intransitive style. Some call these verbs "ambitransitive". The verb "Sing", for example, can be used transitivly:

> - She sings a song.
> - He sings opera.

or intransitivly:

> - She sings all night long.
> - The rails sing after the train passes

When using a verb intransitivly adverbs often follow the verb:

> The rails sing softly after the train passes

but this is not always the case.

> More rapidly than ever he fell.

is an intransitive verb used with a previous adverb. There is no general rule for which verbs can be used in such a construction, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank your answer, it is really useful